# Aligning text in div

Tags: html, css, css-position, text-alignment

How can I get three divs to look as they are shown below with only HTML and CSS? Is it possible to align them in a way that the bottom text will stay under the text which is the longest?

[image: Div aligning]

```
<html>
  <div id=1>
    Short text

    Bottom text?
  </div>
  <div id=2>
    Long text

    Bottom text?
  </div>
  <div id=3>
    Not so long text

    Bottom text?
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: `id="3"` is correct syntax,ALSO, avoid using numbers for id

Comment: I know that, just a fast post ;)

Answer (score 4):

As [@Ruddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840093/aligning-text-in-div/20840225?noredirect=1#comment31257854_20840225) pointed out<sup>Thanks for that</sup>, I used Flexbox approach for this, with CSS Positioning, so am using `display: flex;` for the parent element, and wrapping the bottom text in a `span`, and than am positioning the `span` to `bottom` using `position: absolute;` also, you don't have to assign fixed `height` to the containers, as we are using `display: flex;`

[**Flex Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/35sK9/12/)

```
div.parent {
    display: flex;
}

div.parent > div {
    border: 4px solid #000;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px; /* Make sure you tweak this, to the 
                             highest height of your bottom content*/
}

div.parent > div > span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;left: 0;
}
```

---

Well, obviously you can use `position: absolute;` with `bottom: 0;` with `padding-bottom: 30px;`<sup>*(approx)*</sup> and wrap the bottom text in `span` and use `position: relative;` on the container element but again, you won't be able to stretch the other two containers which doesn't have `height` and thus it will fail.

So you need to use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: bottom;`, it will keep pushing the text to the `bottom` which has content, also, `vertical-align: bottom;` will see to it that even the other containers text stick to the `bottom`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/35sK9/)

```
div.parent {
    display: table;
}

div.parent > div {
    border: 4px solid #000;
    width: 33%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: I didn't opted for a positioning solution because you will need some **fixed height** inorder to keep all the containers equal

Comment: Just make sure you use `width: 100%;` on the container element having `display: table;` http://jsfiddle.net/35sK9/2/

Comment: I don't see how this is correct (even tho they have selected it as correct). This is just pushing **all** the other text to the bottom and the bottom is defined by the longest column. As in the image they displayed it was showing some text being at the top and then the "bottom text" being at the bottom with the top text still at the top in all columns.. OP explain your questions better if this really is correct.

Comment: Just to add onto what I was saying as I'm pretty sure this isn't correct, I think they wanted something like this [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/h5f3g/) In the demo its just an example as the text overlaps at the bottom but you can see the idea. Surely that's what they was saying. Of course I could be completely wrong and making an ass of myself.

Comment: @Ruddy Well, thanks for pointing that out, but, though, you cannot use `position: relative;` on a table cell, your text is overflowing out.. so if OP wants a pure css solution with containers pulling based on other containers height, than this is the only way to achieve, even `position: absolute;` won't help, anyways I am working on this, to retain the text at the top and other text to the bottom

Comment: Oh I know that I was just trying to come up with an example so you could see how it should (kinda) look. If the OP is happy with it that's fine but as I said it doesn't look like what they was asking for. Well good job anyways!

Comment: @OP Give me some time, am off to home, cya for a while

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. But first: give the three a `wrapper`. Beside that, you can't use numbers as ID's.

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/SP68r/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="first">
    Short text

    Bottom text?
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    Long text
      Long text
      Long text
      Long text
      Long text
      <div class="bottom">bottom text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    Not so long text
  </div>
</div>
```

The `CSS`

```
.wrapper { width: 350px; }
#first, #second, #third { float: left; width: 100px;  }
#first { margin-right: 10px; }
#second { padding-bottom: 40px; margin-right: 40px; }
div.bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: This one is not working? it shows at the bottom of everything. That's not the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rhY8J/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="1" style="border: 2px black solid; width: 120px; 
height: 160px; position: relative;">
<div style="text-align: left;" id="1-1">
Not so long text
</div>
<div style="left: 17%;position: absolute; bottom:0px;" id="1-2">
Bottom text?
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution : Use a table.

```
<table border="1" width="100">
<tr valign="top">
    <td>DIV 1</td>
    <td>DIV 2<BR/>THIS IS A BIG, BIG, LONG PARAGRAPH, WHICH WILL GO DOWN THAN     THE OTHER TWO CELLS.</td>
    <td>DIV 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>BOTTOM TEXT</td>
    <td>BOTTOM TEXT</td>
    <td>BOTTOM TEXT</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sivatumma/Fc9mz/).

Comment: This is just nasty.. I would strongly recommend to never ever use tables again for the design of a website. Only if you would like to display data.

Comment: There are many many reasons for it. Such as it makes a very messy code, it uses up more bytes, it's annoying to work with their layout, etc.

I like tables, but only for them to contain data, like gridviews etc.

Comment: I believe there is so much in tables, so many of us ignore its knowledge. [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html), more than that, not jus this question, but for complex ones starting with this question type, you definitely find tables better choice.

Comment: Again, I like tables when they are needed, but i dislike them when they are being used to design the website.

Comment: OP was looking for a solution for his situation instead of an alternative. And using HTML to style your page is just wrong, that is what CSS is for. And using tables is indeed bad because it takes more time to load the pages especially when you nest them. So that is why there is a down vote.